# print contents of pandas dataframe without its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract the contents from `pandas dataframe` without the index.

Dataframe:

```
 L_No          Exp_date
 LC_139        12/01/2019
```

When I do `L_No = df["L_No"]`, I get the output with the index rather than just the L_No.

Current output:

```
 83919     LC_139
```

Expected output:

```
 LC_139
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe need convert column (`Series`) to numpy array or list and select first value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'L_No':['LC_139'],'Exp_date':['12/01/2019']})
print (df)
     L_No    Exp_date
0  LC_139  12/01/2019

print(df["L_No"].values[0])
LC_139

print(df["L_No"].values.tolist()[0])
LC_139
```

If want select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions of first value of column `L_No`:

```
#need first label of index
print(df.loc[df.index[0], "L_No"])
LC_139

#need position of column L_No by get_loc
print(df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc("L_No")])
LC_139
```